# Anchor Link in DataGrid ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, itemtemplate

I have the following markup in a DataGrid:

```
<itemtemplate>
    <a href='~/File.aspx?item=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID").ToString() %>'
        runat='server'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title").ToString() %>
    </a>
</itemtemplate>
```

But it's rendering the following HTML:

<a href="../File.aspx?item=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID").ToString() %>">
    My Link
</a>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this gridview or DataGrid?

Comment: This is a DataGrid, Not a GridView.

Comment: Please be sure to refer about `HyperLinkField` in ASP.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="A1" runat='server' href='<%# "~/File.aspx?item=" + Eval("ID")%>'>
            <%# Eval("Job") %>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @IrishChieftian: long day... i forgot that both had templatefields. the code works fine on DataGrid also. tested that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to append it

```
<a href='~/File.aspx?item=' + <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID").ToString() %>
```

Otherwise if you use hyperlink, It will be very easy. e.g.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ItemID", "~/File.aspx?item={0}")%>'
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title").ToString() %>'></asp:HyperLink>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the link text and what about the closing '>'?

Comment: Are you now able to see the Item id ?

Comment: I have it rendering correctly now except when I add the runat="server" attribute it crashes the page: <a href='~/File.aspx?item=' + '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID").ToString() %>' runat='server'>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title").ToString() %>
                                    </a>

Comment: It's not resolving to the root and the link text is literally: DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title").ToString()

Comment: @Muhammed: +1 for using the eval overload. i forget it every now and then :)